# How To Implement JavaScript Snippet in Magento .PHTML file so that it works?

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, jquery

I want to insert a JavaScript snippet in a Magento .phtml template file. Please, refer to the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004584/dynamically-add-css-class-to-fixed-div-when-it-is-scrolled-to-another-html-eleme) to review the JS snippet - it is the snippet of the chosen best answer:

```
$(function() {
var menu = $('#fixedbtn');
function isInViewport($this) {
   var elementTop = $this.offset().top;
   var elementBottom = elementTop + $this.outerHeight();
   var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
if(elementTop < viewportBottom ==true){
    menu.addClass('fixedPosition');
}else { 
    menu.removeClass('fixedPosition');
 }
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
isInViewport($('#footer-1'))
});
});
```

Now, this code works perfectly in a standard HTML file on a non-server environment. However, when I tried to implement it in a Magento website, it just doesn't work. I tried including it in my app.js, then tried placing it on the page itself between script tags. I tried replacing the $ with jQuery, alas, nothing seems to work.

How can I implement this JavaScript code in Magento template file? Could you please guide me in how I need to format the code, so that it works in Magento (2.1.8)?

**Follow up:**

Alright, at this point I'm quite unsure why the above code will not work as inline script on Magento .phtml template file. I've used JavaScript in this Magento set-up before, both in app.js and also as inline script all working fine. Here, for example, I have the following JS code snippet in copyright.phtml working just fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 800) {
        jQuery('#back-top').fadeIn(); 
        jQuery('#back-top').style.display = "block";  
    } else {
        jQuery('#back-top').fadeOut();
        jQuery('#back-top').style.display = "none";
    }
});
   jQuery('#back-top').click(function() {
    jQuery('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},500);
});   
});
</script>
```

I also added the following script inline:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery','domReady!'], function($){
console.log('hello world');
})
</script>
```

And "hello world" comes out as output in console upon page reload = so no problem with caches or script parsing. I place the desired JavaScript code within

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery','domReady!'], function($){
..desired code snippet here.....
})
</script>
```

Reload page, and... it does not work. Odd? Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution:** replace

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
```

with

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
```

and make sure all your JavaScript code, whether inline or in a custom app.js file is wrapped in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
.....your code here....
});
```

Of course, you can also use *require_config.js*, as per Magento 2 recommendations. That way is tidier, I guess, but harder for newbies.

Also, since adding event listener on the scroll event creates a ton of scroll events, as can be seen in browser web inspector tools >> console logs, we can use additional scripts like *lodash.js* to reduce server load, if this turns out to be a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cover it with:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jqueryui'
    ], function ($) {

   ... Your code ...

    });
</script>
```

That's how to place script inside .phtml.
Another option to include it with requirejs. Google it.

Comment: Wrapping the code snippet in the suggested format does not work either.

Comment: @IvetaAllogenes this should work, did you clear all caches?

Comment: Yes, I did clear css/js cache, flushed cache. Still no success.  I placed the code in copyright.phtml, so that it will load at the footer. I also removed the 'jqueryui' from the require statements, as I don't need it in this case, correct? And I was getting error message for it in the console, not being found. 

When I view page source, I can see that the script shows up at the bottom of the page = no old cache issue, correct?

Comment: Did you tried to replace "JQuery" with $ ?

Comment: I have found that using jQuery instead of $ makes the difference between working and not working for JS scripts in Magento 2. If you don't use RequireJS that is..